# How to access arg/args (passed by `GridCompute.apply()`) from GridClosure?

Tags: caching, closures, gridgain, grid-computing

`GridCompute.apply()` allows to pass a single `arg` or `Collection<> args` but I don't see how to access it/them inside `GridClosure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain will create as many closures as there are arguments and will pass individual argument into `GridClosure.apply(arg)` method.

So, if you pass a Collection<> of 10 args, GridGain will create 10 closures, one for each argument, and will evenly load balance them across the grid.